# Mercurial.Net pullCommand using authorization

Tags: c#, mercurial

I am trying to pull code changes from Mercurial using Mercurial.NET library. I get an authorization exception and do not obtain any results, below is the code.

```
Repository repository = new Repository(@"D:\sandeep\work\20Dec2016");

PullCommand pullcommand = new PullCommand();
repository.Pull(pullcommand);
```

This is my code, is there a way, I can specify my credentials (username and password) for authentication in order to pull the recent changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could achieve the result with the below code and help from Lasse V. Karlsen

```
Repository repository = new Repository(@"D:\sandeep\Work\20Dec2016");
pullCommand.WithConfigurationOverride("auth", "x.prefix", "*");
pullCommand.WithConfigurationOverride("auth", "x.username", "ssk");
pullCommand.WithConfigurationOverride("auth", "x.password", "ssk");
repository.Pull(pullCommand);
```